# Liquibase + H2 + Junit Primary Key Sequence starts over

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, liquibase

I managed to integrate Liquibase into our Maven build to initialize a H2 inmemory database with a few enrys. Those rows have the primary key generated using a sequence table which works as expected (BigInt incremented values starting from 1).

My issue is that when i try to persist a new entity into that table from within a Junit integration test i get a "unique key constraint violation" because that new entity has the same primary key as the very first row inserted using the Liquibase changelog-xmls.

So the initialisation works perfectly fine as expected. The maven build uses the liquibase changelog-xmls

For now i just wipe the according tables completly before any integration tests with an own Runner... but that wont be a possibility in the furture. Its currently quite a chalange to investigate such issues since there is not yet much specific information on Liquibase available.

**Update Workaround**

While id prefer below answer using H2 brings up the problem that below changeset wont work because the required minValue is not supported.

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="alterSequence-example">
  <alterSequence 
        incrementBy="1"
        maxValue="371717"
        minValue="40"
        ordered="true"
        schemaName="public"
        sequenceName="seq_id"/>
```

As a simple workaround i now just drop the existing sequence that was used to insert my testdata in a second changeSet:

```
 <changeSet id="2" author="Me">

    <dropSequence
        sequenceName="SEQ_KEY_MY_TBL"/>

    <createSequence 
        sequenceName="SEQ_KEY_MY_TBL" 
        incrementBy="1" 
        startValue="40"/>
</changeSet>
```

This way the values configured in the changelog-*.xml will be inserted using the sequence with an initial value of 1. I insert 30 rows so Keys 1-30 are used. After that the sequence gets dropped and recreated with a higher startValue. This way when persisting entities from within a Junit based integration Test the new entities will have primary keys starting from 40 and the previous unique constraint problem is solved.

Not H2 will probably soon release a version supporting minValue/maxValue since the according patch already exists.

**Update:**

Maybe we should mention this still is just a Workaround, anyone knows if H2 supports a Sequence with Liquibase that wont start over after DB-Init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instruct liquibase to set the start value for those sequences to a value beyond those you have used for the entries you created. Liquibase has an [alterSequence](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/alter_sequence.html) element for this. You can add such elements at the end of your current liquibase script.

Comment: Thanks for the input, sounds great but unfortunately seems not to be supported by H2 (minValue...). Snap! Wonder if i figure out a way to do this...

Comment: I figured out a simple workaround for H2, by dropping the sequence and create a new one with a higher start value as you suggested, now everything works fine. Very many thanks!